# MySQL ERROR 1064 Creating table syntax

Tags: database, ubuntu, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Every time I'm trying to make new table in database (which I successful can create) I get 1064 Error. I've already tried to make via terminal and by phpstorm database GUI. The weird thing is that `FriendsOfSymfonyBundle` has created table in my database (by typing `doctrine:schema:update`) but I can't do it manually.

Example of code:

> CREATE TABLE test.nameoftable
>   (
>      firstcolumnn INT
>   );

EDIT

Using phpstorm gui I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'session set >current_schema = "test"' at line 1

Comment: Have you tried to look up the error code? This is one of the first results I got from Google, maybe it's helpful: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: I think's it none of this